# Перебор массива #1 в массиве #2, при совпадении перебора, изменить массив #2 или создать отдельный

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Добрый вечер! Борюсь с переборами долгое время, поможете разобраться?
Допустим есть массивы #1 и #2, сейчас их представлю ниже:

---

```
var array1 = [
 {elem_id: 1, name: 'Watch', active: true},
 {elem_id: 2, name: 'System', active: false},
 {elem_id: 3, name: 'Process', active: false,
 ...
 ];

var array2 = [
 {category: 'App', name: 'Watch', active: false},
 {category: 'App', name: 'Table', active: true},
 {category: 'App', name: 'System', active: false},
 {category: 'App', name: 'Process', active: true},
 ...
 ];
```

Нужно добиться такого, чтобы на выходе получился массив с совместными данными. Проверка должна быть по 'name'. Если совпадает, то значение 'active', должно перекочевать из массива #1 и массив #2. Сейчас изображу что должно выйти в итоге из моих примеров.

---

Т.к. в первом массиве и во втором находятся одинаковые 'name' — это "Watch, System, Process", то в массив #3 попадают все данные второго массива, но с параметрами 'active' из первого массива. Итог:

```
var array3 = [
 {category: 'App', name: 'Watch', active: true}, // было false, стало true;
 {category: 'App', name: 'Table', active: true},
 {category: 'App', name: 'System', active: false},
 {category: 'App', name: 'Process', active: false}, // было true, стало false;
 ...
 ];
```

---

**Спасибо огромное!**

Comment: Используйте ключи вместо перебора - если  'Watch','System',.. станут ключами массивов (то есть это уже будет не массив а объект для JS). То алгоритм будет гораздо проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array1 = [{ elem_id: 1 ,name: 'Watch', active: true },
  { elem_id: 2, name: 'System', active: false },
  { elem_id: 3, name: 'Process', active: false }];

var array2 = [{ category: 'App', name: 'Watch', active: false },
  { category: 'App', name: 'Table', active: true },
  { category: 'App', name: 'System', active: false },
  { category: 'App', name: 'Process', active: true }];

var array3 = [];

for (var obj of array2) {

  /* ищем элемент первого массива с соответсвующим именем */
  var obj1 = array1.find((el) => {
    if (el.name == obj.name)
      return el;
  });

  var active;

  /* вычисляем active */
  if (obj1) {
    active = obj1.active;
  } else {
    active = obj.active;
  }

  /* создаём объект для нового результирующего массива array3 
       на основе obj из array2 */
  var newObj = Object.assign({},obj);

  /* задаём active */
  newObj.active = active;

  /* добавляем в array3 */
  array3.push(newObj);
}

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает + разобрался!